# How to test render_to_response in Pyramid Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have a piece of code that calls Pyramid's render_to_response.  I am not quite sure how to test that piece.  In my test, the request object that is sent in is a DummyRequest by Pyramid. How can I capture `to_be_rendered`.

```
from pyramid.renderers import render_to_response

def custom_adapter(response):
    data = {
        'message': response.message
    }

    to_be_rendered = render_to_response(response.renderer, data)

    to_be_rendered.status_int = response.status_code
    return to_be_rendered
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `render_to_response` should return a [response](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/webob.html#response) object.  You should be able to call `custom_adapter` directly in your unit test, providing a `DummyRequest` and make assertions on the `Response` object returned by your `custom_adapter`

```
def test_custom_adapter(self):
   dummy = DummyRequest() # not sure of the object here
   response = custom_adapter(dummy)
   self.assertEqual(response.status, 200)
```